# Adding more than one list

Tags: python

I want to try the  many ways the function of python
So, I want to not use zip use other python function ,how can i do to?

this is use zip and adding more than one list:
but i want to other way not use zip:

```
x = [12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 29]
y = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]

def add_list(i, j):
    l = []
    for n, m in zip(x, y):
        l.append(n + m)
    return l
```

i know this way,

Comment: It's a good thing code can speak for you, because your English sentences are un-parseable. Still, even *with* the code I am not seeing what you are asking.

Comment: not so sure what you mean... are you asking if you can use functionality similar to zip without using zip? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

**without** using `zip`, you can use `map`:

```
from operator import add

x = [12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 29]
y = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
res = map(add, x, y)
# [22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 47]
```

Note that if the iterables are of different lengths, than the shortest will be padded with `None` which will cause a `TypeError` in the `add` instead of `zip` which will truncate to the shortest list.

**On an aside** there's absolutely nothing wrong with using `zip` - I'd probably re-write it as a list-comp though, eg:

```
[sum(items) for items in zip(x, y)]
```

This then scales easily to doing `zip(x, y, z, another_list)` etc...

Answer (score 0):

oh, there are plenty of possibilities, here are a few:

```
# most simple way
res = []
for i in range(len(x)):
  res.append(x[i]+y[i])

# this is the same as
res = [x[i]+y[i] for i in range(len(x))]

# more pythonic
from operator import add
res = map(add, x, y)

# less pytonic
res = map(int.__add__, x, y)

# using numpy
import numpy as np
res = list(np.array(x) + np.array(y))

# alternatively
res = list(np.add(x, y))

# also
res = list(np.sum([x,y], axis=0))
```

Comment: `map(int.__add__, x, y)` will also fail on non-ints... so if any `floats` or other objects that could naturally be added to `int`s will break